# Chrome dev tools say overflow-y: visible even though the only rule applied says something else

Tags: css

Is there something special about tables and overflow?

I'm trying to get a scrollbar into place on an ExtJS tree panel. The appropriate overflow styles are in place down to a table node, which manifests with `overflow: visible;` I added a CSS rule to fix this.

Chrome dev tools still show `overflow-y: visible`, but then shows an arrow, which when checked, shows my rule in gray. (All in computed styles.) In the 'Styles' below, there's nothing that mentions overflow except my rule.

I don't get a scrollbar in either Chrome or FF.

```
overflow-y: visible;
  #netree-body table.x-grid-table - scroll !important
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `overflow` style isn't applicable for table row and cell elements unless their display style is changed to `inline-block` or `block`. e.g.: `display:inline-block; overflow-y:scroll;`. Note that, this change can affect the table layout.

Comment: Got it. Make an answer? Our close as dup?

Comment: Dupe is OK. Unless you need a posted answer.